# AngularJS - Error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm new to AngularJS, and have been working on a small website. At the moment, I'm just getting all the pages to link together and create a distribution folder with Gulp. The distribution gets created no problem, but I end up getting the above-mentioned error. Here's my code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="arabicApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
         content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>    
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>

    <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
        <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>-->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>-->
    <!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('arabicApp', ['ui-router', 'ngResource'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url:'/',
                views: {
                    'sidebar': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/sidebar.html',
                    },
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
                        //controller  : 'IndexController'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.verbSelect', {
                url: 'verbSelect',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/VerbSelect.html',
                        //controller: 'verbsController'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.verbPractice', {
                url: 'verbPractice',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/verbPractice.html',
                        //controller: 'verbsController'
                    }
                }
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    })
;
```

sidebar.html

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Lessons</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="app.verbSelect">Verbs</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="app">Nouns</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my gulpfile.js if that helps

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    stylish = require('jshint-stylish'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    usemin = require('gulp-usemin'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    ngannotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate'),
    del = require('del');

gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
  .pipe(jshint())
  .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});

// Clean
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del(['dist']);
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start('usemin', 'imagemin','copyfonts');
});

gulp.task('usemin',['jshint'], function () {
  return gulp.src('./app/**/*.html')
      .pipe(usemin({
        css:[minifycss(),rev()],
        js: [ngannotate(),uglify(),rev()]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

// Images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  return del(['dist/images']), gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Images task complete' }));
});

gulp.task('copyfonts', ['clean'], function() {
   gulp.src('./bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}*')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));
   gulp.src('./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}*')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() {
  // Watch .js files
  gulp.watch('{app/scripts/**/*.js,app/styles/**/*.css,app/**/*.html}', ['usemin']);
      // Watch image files
  gulp.watch('app/images/**/*', ['imagemin']);

});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['default'], function () {
   var files = [
      'app/**/*.html',
      'app/styles/**/*.css',
      'app/images/**/*.png',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'dist/**/*'
   ];

   browserSync.init(files, {
      server: {
         baseDir: "dist",
         index: "index.html"
      }
   });
        // Watch any files in dist/, reload on change
  gulp.watch(['dist/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    });
```

Could someone please explain what I'm missing here? Apparently, I'm not including something that I should've. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Edit: Here's the error

```
main-665edfe53c.js:1 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=arabicApp&p1=Error%…20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fscripts%2Fmain-665edfe53c.js%3A1%3A8239)
    at main-665edfe53c.js:1
    at main-665edfe53c.js:1
    at o (main-665edfe53c.js:1)
    at u (main-665edfe53c.js:1)
    at Bt (main-665edfe53c.js:1)
    at i (main-665edfe53c.js:1)
    at Q (main-665edfe53c.js:1)
    at X (main-665edfe53c.js:1)
    at main-665edfe53c.js:6
    at HTMLDocument.n (main-665edfe53c.js:1)
```

Edit: Here's my bower.json file. I think it might be worth including here

```
{
  "name": "class",
  "description": "Arabic Class",
  "main": "index.html",
  "keywords": [
    "Arabic",
    "Class",
    "Practice"
  ],
  "authors": [
    "Ba"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.4",
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.4.2"
  }
}
```

Edit: The error was caused by the fact the I added the dependency 'ui-router' in my app.js file. After two days of trying to find the problem, I realized I had to add 'ui.router' instead. That was frustrating!

Comment: Can you share the full error trace from console? which module does it complaining about?

Comment: @Pete. Sure. I'll edit my post

Comment: I hope you checked the angular errors page(the url in error log). Also I see the `'ngResource'` dependency in your app but it does not seems to be included. ngResource comes in a separate js file its not included in `angular.js`. you can get it from https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular-resource.js

Comment: @Pete: Thanks. I looked over the URL, and saw that it was mentioning ngRoute for some reason. I installed and included angular-route.min.js in my index.html file as well as including the angular-resource.min.js file. However, I still end up getting the same error. The URL still mentions ngRoute for some reason. I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: I don't see reference to `angular-resource.js` in your `index.html`. It has _angular.min.js_ and _angular-ui-router.min.js_.Please add `angular-resource.min.js` too. Or try by removing the `'ngResource'` dependency from the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or, if using bower:

`bower install angular-resource#1.6.4`

and then add to your index.html:

`<script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>`

Also inject your dependencies with an array of strings when minifying. See [a note on minification](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#a-note-on-minification) from the AngularJS docs.

Here is your config injected with the [inject property annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation):

```
// arabic-app.module.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('arabicApp', ['ui-router', 'ngResource']);

})();

// arabic-app.config.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('arabicApp').config(Config);

  Config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider']

  function Config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          'sidebar': {
            templateUrl: 'views/sidebar.html',
          },
          'content': {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            //controller  : 'IndexController'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.verbSelect', {
        url: 'verbSelect',
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/VerbSelect.html',
            //controller: 'verbsController'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.verbPractice', {
        url: 'verbPractice',
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/verbPractice.html',
            //controller: 'verbsController'
          }
        }
      });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I replaced my app.js file with yours, however I still get the same error.

Comment: You also are missing [`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource), see my updated answer

Comment: I actually ended up including the angular-resource.min.js file after downloading it with bower. See my comment above. However, I'm still getting the same error. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this damn error just won't go away no matter what I try.

Comment: It's because you have not included ngResource

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141687/discussion-between-the-questioner-and-cnorthfield).